# How to get a js File in firebase storage and import it into react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase

I have a js file saved in my storage that is a array of objects and I need to import it into a class in react. I tried getting it by using the downloadURL but that didn't work. I'm assuming that's because its getting returned as a string since i was just fetching the download url and not the actual page. [![Format of js file][1]][1]

The path in the bucket is; bucket-name/questions/questions.js

This is the format of the js file I need to download incase anyone is wondering.
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JYr80.png

The reason I'm doing this is because the questions might be modified from the console and I need to be able to always get the new questions. I used to have a separate questions.js file already in my program, but since the person changing the questions wants to change the questions from the console and not in the program files. If theres a better way to do this please let me know

Comment: Did you consider storing the JSON in Firebase's Realtime Database? That's a JSON database, so it should be a fairly straightforward move. You can then import it into your existing app without even using its SDK, just through its REST API: https://yourproject.frebaseio.com/questions.json`, and then you can either modify the questions through the Firebase console, or by building a small web app (that then *does* use the SDK)(.

Comment: No i haven’t. I’m going to try it out right now, thank you!